# Flutter Parsing data is null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Got an error that some of my data in my data model are returning values of null but the rest are returning their correct value what could this be?

Below is how the user data is getting registered into the database

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(
    {@required String displayName, 
    @required String fullName, 
    @required String email,  
    @required String password,
    String userRole = 'user',
    String scans = '0',
    String scansLeft = '10',
    }
    ) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.trim(), password: password.trim());
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      // create a new document for the user with the uid
      await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).setData({ 'displayName': displayName, 'fullName': fullName, 'email': email, 'userRole': userRole});


      //creates sub collection points 
      await Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).collection('points').document(user.uid).setData({'scans': scans, 'scansLeft': scansLeft});

      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    } 
  }
```

This is the class model below

```
class User {

  final String uid;
  final String displayName;
  final String fullName;
  final String email;
  final String userRole;
  final String scans;
  final String scansLeft;

  User({this.uid, this.displayName, this.email, 
  this.fullName, this.userRole, this.scans, this.scansLeft});
}
```